# Is there a way to save and open "workspaces" in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

When I'm about to work on *Project Foo*, I want to open all documents and spreadsheets related to *Project Foo* with one click of a link. Is it possible to set up such a link? (Does Google Drive have a concept of a saveable "workspace"?)

Comment: 'Does Google Drive have a concept of a saveable "workspace"?' No. Not to say they wouldn't add something in the future. If you are syncing Drive files with your hard drive, you could always use your OS to open multiple files using your file explorer (or equivalent).

Comment: If you want, sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Google Drive have a concept of a saveable "workspace"?

No. (Not to say they wouldn't add something like that in the future.)

Of course, if you are syncing Drive files with your hard drive, you could always use your OS to open multiple files using your file explorer (or equivalent).

Comment: Google Workspace is available now.

Answer (score 0):

Google now provide a concept of [Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7059647?hl=en).

**As in Doc:**

> This feature helps with version control by enabling you to revert changes to a previous workspace configuration, and helps prevent teammates from inadvertently publishing someone else's unfinished changes